# MySQL Tracking Slow Update Statements

Tags: mysql, performance

I am curious on how to actually record / find out slow UPDATE statements.

I am aware that there is `slow_query_log` option but I found that in this file, no UPDATE statements (i.e. `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT`) are included within the log file.

Some suggested using `binary log` but somehow when I tried to read this in a slave database, most of the UPDATE statements are showing 0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do this in the application, but otherwise the mysql binary log is the only source of such info I can think of.

However you should use the master binary log, because the slave will include the time it is lagging behind the master. Here is an excerpt from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlbinlog.html)

> exec_time is the time spent executing the event, on a master server.
>   On a slave, it is the difference of the end execution time on the
>   slave minus the beginning execution time on the master. The difference
>   serves as an indicator of how much replication lags behind the master

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use performance schema created and maintained by MYSQL engine internally for database statistics.

you can get all required information about performance and slow queries/updates/selects etc.
and from that information you can think of tuning it.